# z83v intel x5-z8350 Audio dont work on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, intel, atom

We have more than 100 units of z83v intel atom x5-z8350 working with ubuntu 16.04 lts. See this link https://www.gearbest.com/tv-box-mini-pc/pp_616708.html

But audio  dont work on ubuntu 16.04 lts with z83v.

Please, could you indicate if there are any drivers that operate with this z83v.

## below command result

sudo lshw -C sound

*-usb:1

```
   description: Audio device
   product: USB Audio Device
   vendor: GeneralPlus
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:3
   version: 1.00
   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 36)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 36)

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 36)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 36)

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 36)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 36)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 36)

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

## Information of the sound device obtained in windows 10

Device Name:Intel SST Audio Device (WDM)

Hardware ID:ACPI\VEN_8086&DEV_22A8

ACPI\808622A8 <---- Device ID matches with our database

*808622A8

if there are no audio drivers for this z83v, I would appreciate it if you tell us which usb sound card works properly with ubuntu 16.04 lts

Regards

Claudio

Comment: Most boxes are manufactured with different components during their life, so rather than looking at specific models (*the link you provided gave no details of sound chips used anyway*) its better to use the hardware used during manufacture; eg. `lspci; sudo lshw -C sound` (edit your question adding results to question please)

Comment: I adding more information of sound device Device Name:Intel SST Audio Device (WDM)

Hardware ID:ACPI\VEN_8086&DEV_22A8